# Needing to calculate pi to 30 digits, but after the 15th digit they all fail

Tags: python, while-loop, series

I am having a problem with series calculations in python where they all fail after the 15th digit. I am using Canopy.

**For example**

3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751 Actual pi
3.14159265358979444826559301873203366994857788085938 My result
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971XXXXXXXXXX The question

The equation 16arctan(1/5) - 4arctan(1/239):

```
    # For Machin
    mm = 0.
    totalm1 = 0.
    while mm <= 100:
        machin1 = (16.)*(-1)**(mm)*((1./5)**(1+2.*mm))/(2.*mm+1) -(4.)*(-1)**(mm)*((1./239)**(1+2.*mm))/(2.*mm+1)
        totalm1 += machin1
        mm += 1
    print "%50.50f" %totalm1
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point numbers only have about 15 digits of precision. If you need more significant digits, use an arbitrary-precision math library. The built-in [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module may be suitable, or you could try [`mpmath`](https://code.google.com/p/mpmath/), which seems to have a lot more features.

An example of computing the square root of 2 with the `decimal` module:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().prec = 50 # Compute with 50 digits of precision
>>> decimal.Decimal('2') ** decimal.Decimal('0.5')
Decimal('1.4142135623730950488016887242096980785696718753769')
```

Comment: How do I go about using such a thing?

Comment: @user3236112: That's a question better answered by the relevant documentation. Short, oversimplified answer: create arbitrary-precision numbers initialized from strings and do math with them as usual.

Comment: Well, if anything that has confused me even further considering I just started my class in python barely 3 weeks ago

Comment: @user3236112: Is this an assignment for class? It seems odd that they'd give you an assignment that requires arbitrary-precision math so soon.

Comment: If it were possible, could you give me an example of arbitrary-precision math for say square root of 2?

Comment: @user3236112: Sure, here you go. Before you try to do your assignment with arbitrary-precision math, though, I'd reread the problem carefully. Check whether you're supposed to be doing something else.